# Removing all spaces from a row of Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove all spaces (both beginning, end, middle, and anywhere else they may be) from each cell in row 3 of Excel. So far I have been able to successfully trim the rows, but that only removes a space at the end.

Could someone help me develop a VBA code that can remove all spaces from the entire row?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Trim()
    [3:3] = [if(3:3<>"",trim(3:3),"")]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
Rows(3).Replace " ", ""
```

Comment: `Trim` specifically does not remove single spaces between words.